# Bind data from form2 datatable to form1 datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on Windows application in c# and want to pass data from one form to another form.

My code on form 2:-

```
Form1 f1= new Form1();
DataTable dt= new DataTable();
dt= calling.GetData(); // get data from database using storedprocedure in datatable

f1.datagridview1.Columns["NameGV"].DataPropertyName= dt.Columns["Name"].ToString();
f1.datagridview1.Columns["AgeGV"].DataPropertyName= dt.Columns["Age"].ToString();
f1.datagridview1.Columns["AddressGV"].DataPropertyName= dt.Columns["Address"].ToString();

f1.datagriidview1.DataSource= dt;
```

It is not working. I have made `datagridview1` public on `form1`. but unable to get data on datagridview.

Comment: If `Form1` is an existing Form, `new Form1()` creates a new, distinct, Form object, not related to the existing Form1. If Form1 doesn't exist yet, your new Form1 is never shown. -- If Form1 exists, then pass to its instance the DataTable, a BindingSource set to the DataTable (if two-way binding is required) or let Form1 call `.GetData()`. -- A better description of your scenario wouldn't hurt (so you could explain why you're setting the `DataPropertyName` of some, apparently pre-existing, Columns).

Comment: If I use GetData() function on Form1 Load it will decrease the performance.  I am using DataPropertyName because on form2 I have a DataTable which has 3 columns and when I select any row on form 2 and Click on Button (Pass) it should show the Data on form 1 datagridview, and Datagridview column index on form 1 and Datable columns index on form 2 must be in same order otherwise I will get existing datagridview columns + Datable columns on the same datagridview.

Comment: I have to ask from you comment… _”If I use GetData() function on Form1 Load it will decrease the performance.”_ ?  How do you know this?

Comment: I do not think you are following Jimi’s comment. If the posted code is in `Form2` then it will not work as you are expecting. Example, in the posted code, we can see a “NEW” `Form1` `f1` being created. Then the code sets the `datagridview1`’s column property names, then sets the grids data source… but the code “NEVER SHOWS” the form.

Comment: The changes to the form are made as expected, however if you don’t show the form the changes won’t be seen by the user. I am betting the form you are looking at and saying “it is not working” is a “different” `Form1`. It could not possibly be the one in the posted code as it is never shown. I hope that makes sense.